# Not able to prove non regularity using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

$L$ = $0^p1^q0^p$. Where $p, q \geq 0$

Here for any string $w \in L$ , I can have $u$=$0^p$, $x$ = $1^q$ and $v$= $0^p$ and $x^i$ will belong to L for all $i \geq 0$

So how do I prove it to be non regular using pumping lemma as there doesn't exist a string $w \in L$ which cannot be decomposed into the form $ux^iv$ for all $i \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that the pumping lemma guarantees that $|ux| \leq n$, where $n$ is the pumping length (which is also a lower bound on the length of $w$). You can use this condition to forbid the situation you describe.

Comment: Suppose I have w = 00011000. Here |w| = 7.  We can have u = 000, x=1, v=1000 which satisfies pumping lemma. I didn't quite understand your answer. Is n=1 (or pumping length =1) here as we can have $1^q$ alone which belongs to the language.?

Comment: I suggest reviewing the Wikipedia article on the pumping lemma for regular languages (which uses $p$ for the pumping length).

Comment: Is it necessary for p to be **minimum** pumping length?

Comment: It's best for you to try to solve the exercise using my hint, without any further help.